# Transfer data collected from Log Analytics to Blob Storage Account using Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics, azure-storage-account

I am new to Azure, I have created a Custom Log in Azure Log Analytics which is able to capture all the logs placed in a file in my desktop. Now I wish to transfer these logs into a Blob Storage Account using Azure Logic Apps. Can someone explain me in detail how to proceed. Detailed explanation would be appreciated

Comment: Are these lofs always gonna be on your device ? Maybe you should push the log directly to blob storage ????

Comment: @Thomas, Hi, ya that can also be done. But I want to try out with Logic App for learning purpose. Is there any way possible?

Comment: check this article, you need to allow connection between your desktop and azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection